# Sub-Threads for similar questions

Tags: feature-request

In many cases people have questions that are too similar to be their own question, but not similar enough to fix their problem. This is an issue because it causes people to either post redundant questions or comment on an old thread that nobody will see. What I would prepose is to have an option to "post as sub-question" or something like that where it would post the original thread again with the slight variation of the question. Could this be annoying or misused? Is there a feature I am not aware of that does this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is easily already catered for by the ease with which you can copy a link from the original question into the start of your follow up question(s). That link automatically expands to show you its title.

If there are "questions that are too similar to be their own question" and they are not duplicates then they are nevertheless questions in their own right and need to standalone with no more than links to other questions for background reading by those who are interested to follow them.

As commented by @JasonC:

> Adding to this, any questions linked from any point (question,
>   answers, comments) in the current question (or to the current question
>   from anywhere else) will appear in the "Linked" section on the sidebar
>   on the right, allowing easy navigation.

Comment: Thank you for that useful bit of information. Will that follow up question be recirculated through stack overflow or will only the original responders see the follow up question?

Comment: It will have the same visibility as any question because it is just another question.  Note that threads are used by discussion forums but in focused Q&A are an alien concept.

Comment: Adding to this, any questions linked from any point (question, answers, comments) in the current question (or *to* the current question from anywhere else) will appear in the "Linked" section on the sidebar on the right, allowing easy navigation.